# How to integrate spring security authentication using public key in multi-module project in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jwt

My project is multi-module base.
like,

```
> e-commerce
    > auth-service 
        > .../AuthService.java
        > pom.xml
    > category-product-service
        > .../CategoryProductService.java
        > pom.xml
> pom.xml
```

E-commerce               : Base module which contain common pom file.

Auth-Service             : integrate spring security mechanism with JWT.(Port-8001)

Categroy-Product-Service : This module have rest-api of category and product.(Port-8002)

Now my question is, How to authenticate category module using auth-service configuration?

I try some public key / private key scenario but it can't work.

Can some one provide some proper solution?

Thanks in advance.